# Managing redirection according to IP Location

Tags: jquery, redirect, caching, response, geoip

We're using Geo IP to redirect to the international site when the IP is from another country, but we're having some problems so we want to ask to the user if he/she wants to keep in the regular site or goes to the international.

I have a fancybox (so jquery) that is fired when the IP looks from another country, now I want to know what can I do to cache (or something like that) the answer and don't show that message again.

Because if you go to another page it's fired again

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: window.location.origin + '/mysite/geoIp/geoip.php',
        success: function(result){
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            if (json.countryCode !== 'MX') {
                jQuery.fancybox({ //Fancybox with the question
                    href: '#country-box', 
                    modal: true
                });
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this is to set a session cookie once a user has seen the modal box.  You can keep this in jQuery using the jquery cookie library - https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

set the cookie once you have the users answer:

```
$.cookie('language_modal_seen', 'value');
```

and check for it's existance before showing the modal

```
if($.cookie('language_modal_seen') === 'value'){
    //show the modal or not
}
```

Hope this helps.